# Can't execute automated test with gulp

Tags: gulp, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

i'm trying to execute my cucumber test with `. ./env/config.env && gulp default`
 but is not executed any test but not displaying any error on the panel, instead is displaying this

```
[09:18:53] Using gulpfile 
       ~/tests/e2e/console_bdd/gulpfile.js
[09:18:53] Starting 'default'...
[09:18:53] Starting 'webdriver-update'...
[09:18:53] Starting 'wdUpdate'...
[09:18:53] I/config_source - curl - o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[09:18:53] I/config_source - curl - o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[09:18:53] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
 [09:18:54] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43.zip
[09:18:54] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.43.zip
[09:18:54] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43
[09:18:54] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.43 up to date
[09:18:54] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
[09:18:54] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar up to date
[09:18:56] I/update - geckodriver: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
[09:18:56] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
[09:18:56] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0
[09:18:56] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.23.0 up to date
[09:18:56] Finished 'wdUpdate' after 3.32 s
[09:18:56] Finished 'webdriver-update' after 3.33 s
[09:18:56] Starting 'e2e'...
[09:18:56] Starting 'webdriver-update'...
[09:18:56] Starting 'wdUpdate'...
[09:18:57] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43.zip
[09:18:57] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.43.zip
[09:18:57] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43
[09:18:57] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.43 up to date
[09:18:57] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
[09:18:57] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar up to date
[09:18:58] I/update - geckodriver: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
[09:18:58] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
[09:18:58] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0
[09:18:58] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.23.0 up to date
[09:18:58] Finished 'wdUpdate' after 1.64 s
[09:18:58] Finished 'webdriver-update' after 1.64 s
[09:18:58] Finished 'e2e' after 1.64 s
[09:18:58] Finished 'default' after 4.97 s
Admins-MacBook-Pro:console_bdd jesus.burquez$
Admins-MacBook-Pro:console_bdd jesus.burquez$ . ./env/config.env && gulp default
[10:30:19] Using gulpfile ~/janrain/console/tests/e2e/console_bdd/gulpfile.js
[10:30:19] Starting 'default'...
[10:30:19] Starting 'webdriver-update'...
[10:30:19] Starting 'e2e'...
[10:30:19] Starting 'wdUpdate'...
[10:30:19] Starting 'webdriver-update'...
[10:30:19] Starting 'wdUpdate'...
[10:30:19] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[10:30:19] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[10:30:19] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[10:30:19] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[10:30:19] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
[10:30:19] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
[10:30:20] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
[10:30:20] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar up to date
[10:30:20] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43.zip
[10:30:20] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.43.zip
[10:30:20] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43.zip
[10:30:20] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.43.zip
[10:30:20] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43
[10:30:20] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.43 up to date
  [10:30:20] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
 [10:30:20] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar up to date
 [10:30:20] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43
[10:30:20] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.43 up to date
 [10:30:21] I/update - geckodriver: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
 [10:30:21] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
[10:30:21] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0
[10:30:21] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.23.0 up to date
 [10:30:21] Finished 'wdUpdate' after 2.59 s
[10:30:21] Finished 'webdriver-update' after 2.59 s
[10:30:21] I/update - geckodriver: file exists /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
[10:30:21] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
[10:30:21] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jesus.burquez/janrain/console/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0
[10:30:21] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.23.0 up to date
[10:30:21] Finished 'wdUpdate' after 2.66 s
[10:30:21] Finished 'webdriver-update' after 2.66 s
[10:30:21] Finished 'e2e' after 2.66 s
[10:30:21] Finished 'default' after 2.66 s
```

That's what I get after try to execute, my gulp version is 4.0.0 i'm missing something in the configuration?

hope can help me.

This is my gulp file

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var protractor = require('gulp-protractor').protractor;
var webdriverUpdate = require('gulp-protractor').webdriver_update;

gulp.task('webdriver-update', gulp.series(webdriverUpdate));

gulp.task('e2e', gulp.series('webdriver-update'), function () {
  console.log("line 9")
    return gulp.src('features/*')
      .pipe(protractor({
        configFile: 'e2e-conf.js'
      }))
      .on('error', function (e) { throw e; });
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('webdriver-update', 'e2e'));
```

Comment: Could you share your `gulp` configuration file?

Comment: @Oleksii I add the gulp file conf to the main question

Comment: show `e2e-conf.js` and  seems task `e2e` had did  `webdriver-update`, so taks `default` is no need to do `webdriver-update` again, only `e2e` is ok